# Having trouble with int.parse. Is there a better way to display my timestamp?

Tags: flutter, dart, timestamp, datetime-format

I'm trying to display my timestamp under a chat bubble. I am getting my chat data from my Firebase Database.

When I my code, I get an error saying the source must not be null. After looking into the error, I found that int.parse is causing this issue. Is there a better way I can implement this without using int parse? Or am I using it wrong?

```
Text(DateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy - hh:mm:aa")
    .format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(document['timestamp']))),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Is document['timestamp'] of type string? Could you tell us what its value is?

Comment: Yes it is stored as a string in Firebase. The value of the timestamps are 13 digit values such as this "1598993438350" for example.

Comment: Try print(document['timestamp']) to be sure it is not null. Because the int.parse() is telling it is null.

Comment: So it is printing as null. Do you know why that's happening?

Comment: We can't see the rest of your code, without which it's impossible to know why it is null.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. I stored timestamp in Firebase as "timeStamp" so I was calling an incorrect value. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I stored "timestamp" in Firebase as "timeStamp" so I was calling an incorrect value. And I was printing "timestamp" which was giving me a null value. Thanks guys